# Cordova build to device on Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

I am using Mac OS X 10.11. I am trying to deploy build to device (iPhone 4) by running `sudo cordova run ios --device` and the build end up with the error message saying: `Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.`

So, now I have pay USD 99 to register the developer program. I have create & download the provisioning profile from the website and double click on it. I think I have successfully add it to xcode. However, why is that when I run `sudo cordova run ios --device`, it still give me the same error? How can I solve it? If you know how, please give me a hand. I have been stuck here for few days.....

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently apple has allowed users to create free developer accounts for their own development, with the caveat being you can't release to their store, only test on your own devices.

Follow the steps included in the following link: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/12/24/how-to-create-a-free-apple-developer-account-xcode/

In short, assuming you have a regular apple id already:

1. [log in to the developer portal](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757) with your regular account.
2. Read and accept the terms
3. Add your new developer account to Xcode, by clicking Xcode → Preferences → Accounts, and the [+] button to add an account.

You can now create a provisioning profile. Hooray!